# problem with content aware fill

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

im new to photoshop, so im watching a tutorial of removing a man from a photo. but content aware fill is not working . i have tried many times. but its not getting removed .This is the before and after picture . i cant see any change. can you pls  help me. [image]

Comment: What version of Photoshop? Content aware fill has been through several major improvements over the past few years. It's still not perfect & that's a tough job you've handed it, but I managed to get this with a simple lasso - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rGY3.jpg

Comment: You say you post a before and after image, but I only see one image. Perhaps you forgot to post the second image?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Content Aware fill does work. Sorry, but I can't replicate your problem. Please note that tech support questions are generally off-topic here because they are difficult to resolve without access to your computer. It's best to get tech support from Adobe directly.Sorry about that.